# install bcrypt-ruby on windows

Tags: bcrypt

I have copy the make.bat to bin\ folder,when run the command gem install bcrypt-ruby,
it shows the bash.exe is not the internal or external command.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install "**bcrypt-ruby**" on **Windows 8, 64 bit** .

Tried a lot of configurations, ranging from different versions of the gem, direct from git, platform ruby etc.

But nothing worked

At the end installed DEVKIT compatible to my ruby version and thats it.

**Steps**

> Install Devkit compatible to your ruby version

Link : http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Download under

```
C:/Ruby Folder/devkit
```

Then on command line go to above path

```
C:/Ruby Folder/devkit
```

then say

```
gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

This should install it,

Post this, you need to add the gem to your Gemfile and say

```
bundle install
bundle update
bundle install
```

This should work fine. Also solves update issues related to active_record etc.

---

> The same should work for WIN 64, WIN 32 also.

---

Comment: Rather than keep adding the same answer to lots of questions, perhaps link the questions to each-other instead? just posting a link as a comment is enough...